# Is there any way to display windows app available using manifest.json as it is displayed in android?

Tags: windows

I use the following `manifest.json` to display Android users that my website has an app available on Google Play Store and when the click on install they are redirected to the app page on the store. Is there any way to do the same for **Windows** users as well?

[image]

Here's the manifest.jason file:

```
{
  "short_name": "ChatAdda",
  "name": "ChatAdda",
  "theme_color": "#075E55",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "display": "standalone",
  "prefer_related_applications": true,
  "related_applications": [
    {
      "platform": "play",
      "id": "com.chatadda.free"
    }
  ],
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "images/launcher-icon-1x.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "48x48"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/launcher-icon-2x.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "96x96"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/launcher-icon-3x.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "144x144"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/launcher-icon-4x.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/?utm_source=launcher"
}
```

Comment: Found solution for Apple App Store: `"platform": "itunes",
      "url": "STORE_URL"`

Comment: If you find solutions, please post answers instead of comments.

Comment: I found half the answer and the main question still remains unanswered so I didn't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

From my knowledge, you should only add a new value in your `related_applications` array:

```
"related_applications": [
    {
      "platform": "play",
      "id": "com.chatadda.free"
    },
    {
      "platform": "windows",
      "url": ""https://www.microsoft.com/DEFAULT_LANG/p/YOUR_APP/ITS_ID"
    }
  ]
```

The list of supported platforms is here: https://github.com/w3c/manifest/wiki/Platforms